# Difference between #seq and seq in F#

Tags: f#

I was wondering what #seq means in the F# interactive shell.
I had a `collect` function with 2 parameters, a function and a sequence, where this function is applied to the sequence.

```
let rec collect f sq =
  seq {
    let a = Seq.item 0 sq
    let sq1 = Seq.skip 1 sq
    let ris = f a
    yield! ris
    yield! collect f sq1
  }
```

When the shell evaluates the `collect` it gives back the following signature

```
val collect: f: ('a -> #seq<'c>) -> sq: seq<'a> -> seq<'c>
```

What does `#` mean before `seq` in this instance?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `seq<'a>` is the F# spelling for `IEnumerable<T>`
- The `#` before a type is a [flexible type annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types). This allows you to use any type that implements the indicated interface.